# Make emacs recognize a file as bash

Tags: bash, emacs

I'm trying to get emacs to recognize that a script (which is supposed to be sourced) is written in bash. I put

```
# this is a -*- bash -*- script
```

on the first line, but it's still opening in `sh` mode. I can get it to work by putting `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on the first line, but I'm reluctant to do that because it makes the script look like it's executable, whereas I want it to be sourced. Why isn't emacs recognizing my hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
# -*- mode: shell-script ; eval: (sh-set-shell "bash") -*-
```

But Emacs will ask you whether you really want to execute insecure code.